# display data in listview from contextMenu

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu, show

I create a listview and I want to send data from MainActivity to UpdateActivity to display the data in it , but when I clicked to any item in listView the item with position 0 is displayed for all the item 
for example I clicked on item with position 4 ,the item with position 0 displayed
where is the problem 
the code in MainActivity

```
int mypos = 0;
List<Employee> list;
MyAdapter adapter;
ListView lv;
```

And this is the code for onClickListener for ListView I set the position to mypos to take the position for the item

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Employee e=list.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ShowdActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MobileId",e.getId());
            intent.putExtra("MobileName",e.getName());
            intent.putExtra("image",e.getImg());
            startActivity(intent);
            mypos = position;
        }
    });
```

This is the code for contextMenu in it update item to send the data to UpdateActivity

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Employee e=list.get(mypos);
 switch (item.getItemId()){
     case R.id.updateOp:
         Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),updateActivity.class);
         intent.putExtra("MobileId",e.getId());
         intent.putExtra("MobileName",e.getName());
         intent.putExtra("image",e.getImg());
         startActivity(intent);
         break;
```

Finaly this is the code for updateActivity to recive the data and display it

```
public class updateActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ImageView imageUpdate;
EditText idUpdate;
EditText nameUpdate;
Button saveUpdate;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update);
    imageUpdate = findViewById(R.id.imageEdit);
    idUpdate = findViewById(R.id.idEdit);
    nameUpdate = findViewById(R.id.nameEdit);
    saveUpdate = findViewById(R.id.saveButton);

    int idupdate = getIntent().getIntExtra("MobileId",0);
    int imagupdate = getIntent().getIntExtra("image",0);
    imageUpdate.setImageResource(imagupdate);
    idUpdate.setText(idupdate+"");
    nameUpdate.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("MobileName"));
}
```

}

Comment: Probably because variable `mypos` is only set with position value when you click on one of the `listview` items instead each another time it is `0` that means you will always get data from first position inside your `List`

Comment: how can I solve this problem ? to take the real position for each item in listview?